# How to embed current time with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` combined with `tee` and `mplayer` to have a simple video livestream and recorder over SSH. Now, I'd love to embed the current (server) time in the stream. The format doesn't matter much, ideally would be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I've found [this](https://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/) how-to suggesting the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 \
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='%{localtime\:%T}': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=700" -vcodec libx264 \
-preset veryfast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

But using the `-vf` portion of this results in the following error for me:

```
[NULL @ 0x55e4ef96b2a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'text=%{localtime:%T}:'
text=%{localtime:%T}:: Invalid argument
```

I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543426/ffmpeg-embed-current-time-in-milliseconds-into-video) command (the third code block in the Q), just to test it, but it failed aswell:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x55fb2862a940] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55fb28629fc0] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'text=%{pts:hms:1553359336.166336638}'
```

Finally, I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208337/q-ffmpeg-drawtext-localtime-video-filter-display-in-custom-format) question, and tried it, slightly modified like this (this is showing my full command, I've only adjusted the `-vf` options in the past two examples):

```
ffmpeg  -r 20 -s 640x480 -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -vf "drawtext=fontsize=90:fontcolor=white: fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf: text='%{localtime\:%X}'" -f avi -
```

This presents me with the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x55ae61d051a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf:'
fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf:: Invalid argument
```

Modifying what I've found [here](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=513) a bit to:

```
-vf drawtext="fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-Light.otf':fontsize=14:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=1:text='%H-%M-%S':x=8:y=8"
```

Presents me with:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x55e36db2aa40] Stray % near 'H-%M-%S'
```

Note that using this comment with *just* text (e.g. `text='test'`) works fine..
Adding [1-4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54046375/9138821) `\`s in front of the `%`s shows no change in error or effect.

My `ffmpeg` version: `ffmpeg version 3.2.12-1~deb9u1` on a debian machine.
It has been compiled with the drawtext library and it is present in `ffmpeg -filters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've found the solution in the [FFmpeg filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion).

> 10.52.2 Text expansion
>
> If expansion is set to strftime, the filter recognizes strftime()
>   sequences in the provided text and expands them accordingly. Check the
>   documentation of strftime(). This feature is deprecated.

Though it says `This feature is deprecated.`, this works just fine for me. Here is my final `-vf`:

```
-vf drawtext="expansion=strftime:fontfile='/usr/share/fonts/cantarell/Cantarell-Light.otf':fontsize=14:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=1:text='%Y-%m-%d\ %H\\\\:%M\\\\:%S':x=8:y=8"
```

Please note that whyever, the four `\\\\` are neccessary to escape `:`. To escape the space, a single `\` is sufficient. The result will look like this:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

The first option, `text='%{localtime\\:T}'` works fine. The OP had his quotes in the wrong place, he had `'text=...'`. You'll note that in subsequent examples, he has the single quotes in the right place.